# How to set useBuiltIns option

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I am using Webpack and want to set Babel "useBuiltIns" option to enable pollyfills for "promises" in my JS files.

I couldn't find a complete working example and all my tries are ending up with an error.

This is my package.json try:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.10.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "lazysizes": "^4.1.7",
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "lg-thumbnail": "^1.2.0",
    "lightgallery": "^1.7.0",
    "owl.carousel": "^2.3.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "yuglify": "^0.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.2",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.8",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "0.4.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack --config webpack.dev.js --watch",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "babel": {
    "useBuiltIns": "entry" <------ this is not working
  }
}
```

According to the docs there is an option. "useBuiltins" available (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill#usage-in-node-browserify-webpack)

According to the docs I can place Babel options into my package.json under "babel" (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/6.26.3/babelrc)

Answer (score 3):

@babel/polyfill is deprecated use core-js and regenerator. This is from https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env "Since @babel/polyfill was deprecated in 7.4.0, we recommend directly adding core-js and setting the version via the corejs option."

Your preset will look like

```
const presets = [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        corejs: { version: 3, proposals: true }
      }
    ],
```

And install

```
 "core-js": "^3.6.5",
"regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.5",
```

And Finally replace @babel/polyfill imports with

```
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
```

And Also you can set the browserlist target to polyfill accordingly

For e.g.

```
"browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11"
  ]
```